# Can't Create a WAV file from voice recognition. (C#)

Tags: c#, wav, voice-recognition

I'm trying to create a program that uses voice recogniton and makes a WAV file from the recognized voice, I used this code :

```
Recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile(@"C:\\Program Files\\MyProgram\\Bin\\STWAV\\Speech.wav");
```

but I'm getting this exception every time I start the voice recognition,

> "Could not locate file C:\Program Files\MyProgram\Bin\STWAV\Speech.wav".

I think that my program don't have a permission to create the WAV file in this path.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing to

```
C:\Program Files\
```

you will need administrator-permission. Try to write the file the user's documents or a similar place.
Using [System.Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) you can get the user's documents-folder easily.

```
string docs = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
docs += "\\Speech.wav";
Recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile(docs);
```

Alternatively, but a bad idea, would be to require the user to start the program as administrator.

---

**EDIT**

The method

```
Recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile
```

is meant to [**READ**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtoaudiostream.aspx) from a file. You cannot use it to store anything in a wav-file.

[Here](http://speechrecognitionblog.blogspot.de/2012/05/audio-recording-and-playback-in-c-net.html) you find a tutorial on how to record speech in .NET.

Comment: Sorry but I'm unable download the SDK, I'll tell you what I'm working on ,I wanna use "google speak now" service in my c# program, and what I wanted to do is turning the speech into a wav file and sending it to google's speech server and getting the recognized voice text.

Comment: So is there another way to create a wav file from recognized voice ?